# how to open the windows explorer map network

Tags: vb.net, dictionary, window, call, powershell-cmdlet

[image: Windows Explorer - Map Network Drive]

Hi All,

I need to be able to open the [Windows Explorer - Map Network Drive] popup using either VB or cmdlet. I tried using the code in both VB and cmdlet:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("rundll32.exe shell32.dll,SHHelpShortcuts_RunDLL Connect")
```

But it does not work.

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit of library magic:

```
Private Declare Function WNetConnectionDialog Lib "mpr.dll" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwType As Long) As Long

Dim ret As Integer = WNetConnectionDialog(Me.hwnd, 1)    'ret is 0 on success
```

Comment: Hi!

Thanks very much. I slightly changed the code and it works!

    Dim ret As Integer = WNetConnectionDialog(Nothing, 1)